# Pip install python.binance

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install python.binance but I'm getting the following warning messages:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/0a/80d87aa4ee79980bddabef13cb7d95de330f85355cf08dfdaf874889b02b/ujson-4.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=c615a9e9e378a7383b756b7e7a73c38b22aeb8967a8bfbffd4741f7ffd043c4d (from https://pypi.org/simple/ujson/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Requested ujson from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/0a/80d87aa4ee79980bddabef13cb7d95de330f85355cf08dfdaf874889b02b/ujson-4.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=c615a9e9e378a7383b756b7e7a73c38b22aeb8967a8bfbffd4741f7ffd043c4d (from python.binance) has inconsistent version: filename has '4.0.2', but metadata has '0.0.0'
```

What can I do to prevent this?

With kind regards,

Lazzanova

Comment: The message says requires-python:>=3.6. Does your version of Python meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```sh
pip install python-binance
```

> https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start